# Truffle - Transfer leads to "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"

Tags: solidity, truffle, error

For reference, I am using Solidity to develop a smart contract for my company. I created a smart contract and attempted to use Truffle and Ganache to unit test it. However, I'm having a bit of an issue with my smart contract returning `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert` when I try to unit test it with Truffle. After testing my code a lot, I have managed to cut down the smart contract to the following code, which still produces the error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Purchase {

 address public buyer;
 address public seller;
 address public companyEscrow;
 uint private moneyInEscrow = 0;

 modifier onlyCompanyEscrow {
    require(
        msg.sender == companyEscrow,
        "Only the escrow account of the company can call this function."
    );
    _;
 }

 modifier onlyBuyer {
    require(
        msg.sender == buyer,
        "Only the buyer can call this function."
    );
    _;
 }

 constructor (address addressSeller, address addressCompanyEscrow) public payable {
    buyer = msg.sender;
    seller = addressSeller;
    companyEscrow = addressCompanyEscrow;
 }

 function sendFundsToCompany ()
      public
      payable
      onlyBuyer
      returns (bool completed)
  {
      moneyInEscrow = msg.value;
      companyEscrow.transfer(moneyInEscrow);
      return true;
  }


  function sendFundsToSeller ()
      public
      payable
      onlyCompanyEscrow
      returns (bool completed)
  {
      seller.transfer(moneyInEscrow);
      moneyInEscrow = 0;
      return true;
  }
}
```

The function sendFundsToCompany() is supposed to be executed first and then afterwards, the function sendFundsToSeller() is supposed to be executed. I cut down my unit testing to the following Truffle unit test, which still produces the error:

```
var Web3Beta = require('web3')
var web3beta = new Web3Beta()
var Purchase = artifacts.require('Purchase')

contract('Purchase', function ([buyer, seller, companyEscrow] {

  var purchase = await Purchase.new(seller, companyEscrow)

  it('Should send funds to seller', async function () {
    var sellerInitialBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(seller).toNumber()
    var companyEscrowInitialBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(companyEscrow).toNumber()

    await purchase.sendFundsToCompany({ value: web3beta.utils.toWei('3', 'ether'), gas: "6600000" })
    await purchase.sendFundsToSeller({ from: companyEscrow, gas: "6600000" })

    assert.isAbove(web3.eth.getBalance(seller).toNumber(), sellerInitialBalance)
    assert.isBelow(web3.eth.getBalance(companyEscrow).toNumber(), companyEscrowInitialBalance)
  })
})
```

I have combed through the Ethereum StackExchange, the Truffle help boards, and the Solidity documentation. However, the bug still eludes me. After looking through similar questions on the Ethereum StackExchange, I performed the following actions:

- I made sure both functions have the 'payable' modifier.
- I explicitly sent the functions a large gas limit.
- I deleted the /builds folder and recompiled everything.
- I ended the current deployment and started a new instance with 'truffle develop'.

Unfortunately, doing these things didn't resolve my problem. I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the problem is. I'm new to Solidity so it's probably something basic; however, I can't seem to figure out what it is.

For reference, my version of Truffle is 4.1.13 and my version of Ganache is 6.1.6 (ganache-core = 2.1.5). Also, I'm running 'truffle develop' and performing my unit tests in two separate command prompts - I run 'truffle develop' in one prompt and only after do I perform the unit tests in the other command prompt.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can provide me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running that in Remix ? Because there everything works fine for me, can you confirm? I suppose it's in the tests somewere. Which of the transaction calls exactly causes the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other issues, but this is certainly one:

```
function sendFundsToCompany ()
    public
    payable
    onlyBuyer
    returns (bool completed)
{
    moneyInEscrow = msg.value;
    companyEscrow.transfer(moneyInEscrow);
    return true;
}
```

If you send this function 1 wei, then `moneyInEscrow == 1`, and that 1 wei is transferred away to `companyEscrow`. So the contract balance remains at 0.

```
function sendFundsToSeller ()
    public
    payable
    onlyCompanyEscrow
    returns (bool completed)
{
    seller.transfer(moneyInEscrow);
    moneyInEscrow = 0;
    return true;
}
```

If you then call this function, an attempt is made to send `moneyInEscrow` (1) wei to `seller`. But the contract balance is 0, so this transfer will fail.